# Can I report users that give self-assured answers that are completely wrong?

Tags: support

I asked a question about interpolating polynomials ([fit numpy polynomials to noisy data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201515/fit-numpy-polynomials-to-noisy-data)) and initially was given really mean-spirited and bad advice. Two particular users gave me a really hard time for asking the question and insisted that my problem was caused by not understanding machine precision. One of those two deleted his answer when the correct answer was posted. These two gave really bad advice, and if I didn't know better, I might have been discouraged and deleted the question. Is there any action I can take against these users besides flagging as breaking the "be nice" policy?

[image: Screenshot of comments]

Comment: Both. The comments mainly. But also the answer Joe gave. All of it was hostile and ill-informed advise.

Comment: Those comments  (twice!) that claim *it should take more than a two second google search* are indeed off-limits. Oh wait, they are yours ...

Comment: Consider anonymizing your screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you shouldn't flag because an answer you feel that it's incorrect. If an answer is wrong and helpful, it's wrong and unhelpful. In that case, downvote it. If others find that it's unhelpful as well, they'll downvote it and cause the answerer to either lose rep, or cause them to outright delete the answer. The former is a just "punishment" for bad answers, and upholds the quality requirements of the site, and the later prevents the bad answer from wasting anyone else's time.

Or, think of it this way: if you flag an answer as factually incorrect, the responding moderator must have domain knowledge to decide what action to take. Voting offloads that work onto the community, where there's a much higher chance of getting someone with domain knowledge to judge the answer. Apparently there's actually a default denial reason for moderators that flags should not be used to report incorrect answers (thanks @Catija for pointing this out).

If you're mad because someone said something snippy to you and proved to be unhelpful later, I'd just cut your losses and move on. If you're on a popular tag, I'd just hope that someone else with more knowledge on the topic sees the question and can give you a better answer later.

---

As for the comment, the "oh boy" bit is a little snooty sounding, but I don't know if that really violates the "be nice" policy. The tone is unfortunate, but I wouldn't go as far as to suggest moderator intervention.

I'll add though because I saw Anne's comment: if someone's commenting just to comment and abusing the purpose of comments (requesting clarification of the question), for the sake of cleaning up the site, you can flag it to have them cleaned. In this case though, it does appear that they are attempting to flesh out a solution by trying to clarify what the problem may be.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know if there was some system for flagging low-quality answers. It seemed like these users might give other question-askers a similarly hard time.

Comment: @kilojoules "quality" is entirely controlled by voting. You can flag answers for more serious offences (like spam, over the top rudeness), but the quality of the answer is a seperate issue. Think of it this way: if you flag an answer as wrong factually, the moderator responding would have to have domain knowledge of the problem to act properly. Voting is a far better mechanism, and offloads that work onto the community instead of moderators.

Comment: If you flagged an answer as "wrong" for a moderator, they'd just decline the flag. There's even a flag decline reason that reads "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

Comment: @Catija Not sure if you're responding to my answer, or their comment. I'll incorporate that information though

Comment: More the comment because you're arguing for voting over flagging... which is definitely the right call... but it's the "right" call **because** flagging is just completely wrong. Feel free to incoroporate it into your answer, though :D

Answer (score 16):

The first thing you need to learn is the difference between an *answer* and a *comment*.

Comments are places to ask for more information or make suggestions that will improve a post. They're not designed to be solutions to the problem. It's true that many people don't use comments appropriately, but going in, you should assume that a comment is just that... a comment. Not a solution.

The first comment from Joe reads like a "[what have you tried already](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rksCTVFtjM4)" question. Which is fair. It's important for us to get a baseline of information about what you've tried already. Whether it's correct or not is immaterial - it's not an answer. And the fact that it has three upvotes from people implies that people agreed it was a good question to ask.

So, answer the question - have you tried it yet... if the answer is "no" - give it a try and explain the result; if the answer is "yes" explain that you've tried it and it doesn't fix your issue.

As to Mad Physicist's comment. I also don't read it as rude. "Oh boy" seems superfluous... but it doesn't make it mean. Regardless, if you feel that something is rude, you can always flag it as such.

There are three reasons for comment flags:

> - rude or abusive
>     This comment violates our "Be Nice" policy.
> - no longer needed
>     This comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary.
> - in need of moderator intervention
>     A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!

If you feel that a comment fits any of these three descriptions, feel free to flag it. Rude fits the first one, something that you think is unneeded would be "no longer needed" - if you've addressed an issue from the comments in your post, that's a good time to use this flag - and you can write a custom flag reason for moderation using the third option.

Do note, Stack Overflow gets lots of comment flags, so I'm not sure you can expect them to be handled immediately and if a moderator disagrees with your flag, they'll decline it.

---

Now, since you mention flagging *answers* as "wrong"... **don't do that**.

We moderators actually have a default flag decline reason that reads:

> Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

So... don't flag answers that are wrong... well... unless you like having your flags declined. When an answer is wrong (if you have sufficient reputation) down vote it to show that it's wrong. Don't flag.

You can certainly flag an answer as rude if you feel that it is, though most answers that are "rude" aren't really answers... at least on sites like Stack Overflow.